# trying to access a url from android activity

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I want to access a url in my android activity, for storing a string thats passed as a parameter on the url itself with a webservice that i have built. at this point, i just want to access the url and see that it happens, and later on i will worry about doing something with the result (what the request returns back). I'm using HttpURLConnection. I'm getting this error:

```
D/SntpClient(   59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address fami
ly not supported by protocol
```

my code is:

```
public void storeScore()
{
    Log.d("storeScore","is running");
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    //DefaultHttpClient
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setReadTimeout(10000);
        con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoInput(true); //also tried without this
        con.setDoOutput(true); //also tried without this
        con.connect();
        Log.d("storeScore","got to connect");
        //not really reading the result at this point:
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        //String payload = reader.readLine();
        //reader.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("MalformedURLException",e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("IOException",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

the app android manifest includes both premissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

this method storeScore() is ran from a thread that is created onCreate and started. Am i doing something wrong here? If you need more relevant information that i didn't add here, tell me and I will edit the question. Thanks, i appreciate any assistance.

Comment: The message says that your phone can't contact the time server, does your code actually crash with that exception or is that just found in the logcat?

Comment: app does not crash, this is just found in logcat. also note this is ran on emulator

Comment: I can't repeat the exception on the Mac so I can verify where it originates from, but it sounds entirely harmless and ignorable.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i see. but is the url being accessed?

Comment: The code looks ok to me at a glance, if you get the log from `Log.d("storeScore","got to connect");`, you should be in good shape.